# Facebook: click "use app", redirect to app store or installed app

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-page, facebook-ads-api

In many facebook pages, when you click on "**use app**" button, it redirects you to the installed app on your phone, or to the app store if the app is not installed.

However, when I try to do the same, it only shows me the option to input a website! **Nowhere I can input an android package name or iOS app id**.

How do those website redirect users to native apps? Where is the option to do it on Facebook, I can't find any documentation on this. Thanks!

You can see there's only the option to add website:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think your page must be categorized as an “app page” for that to work.

Comment: @CBroe Tried, still no use.